# Run multiple commands on command prompt

Tags: c#, command-prompt

I am using this code

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK=\'C:\\app\\dbName_300915_000.bak\'\"");            
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
textBox2.Text = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

to restore a database. My issue here is that I need to run the

```
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK=\'C:\\app\\dbName_300915_000.bak\'\"");
```

multiple times for multiple databases. Do I need to create a different process each time? I could use the `cmd.StandardInput.Writeline` one after another but I want an update on my textbox after each restore is finished.

Comment: Why not to run `SQLCMD` directly from your code? Why do you need `cmd`?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `run SQLCMD directly from your code`, the `SQLCMD` tuns through the command prompt.

Comment: Why not just connect to the sql server in your code, why invoke another process to to do this at all?

Comment: This is also possible, will I get a feedback from the sql server?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a batch file, either manually or through code, and then execute that batch file from the command prompt.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"<location of batch file>\<batch file name>.bat";
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Interesting!! And I could modify that bat file outside my app without having to modify the code!

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do this, for example:

```
Process cmd = new Process();
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
cmd.Start();
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK=\'C:\\app\\dbName_300915_000.bak\'\"");            
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK=\'C:\\app\\dbName_300915_000.bak\'\"");            
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK=\'C:\\app\\dbName_300915_000.bak\'\"");            
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK=\'C:\\app\\dbName_300915_000.bak\'\"");            
cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("SQLCMD -E -S srvName -Q \"RESTORE DATABASE dbName FROM DISK=\'C:\\app\\dbName_300915_000.bak\'\"");            
cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
cmd.StandardInput.Close();
cmd.WaitForExit();
textBox2.Text = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Also, your ReadToEnd() is wrong and can potentially cause deadlocks. See MSDN:

```
// To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: My issue is that I need after each restore to have some kind of feedback and know that it was restored or not. Your solution will provide the info after every backup command is performed.

Comment: Yes, in this case better would be to put the above code into a method and execute it many times. I am right about the deadlock though.